# How to Update Identity's Manage Controller

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-identity-2

This is the default Manage Controller in AccountController.cs

```
  public async Task<ActionResult> Manage(ManageUserViewModel model)
        {
            bool hasPassword = HasPassword();
            ViewBag.HasLocalPassword = hasPassword;
            ViewBag.ReturnUrl = Url.Action("Manage");
            if (hasPassword)
            {
                if (ModelState.IsValid)
                {
                    IdentityResult result = await UserManager.ChangePasswordAsync(User.Identity.GetUserId(), model.OldPassword, model.NewPassword);
                    if (result.Succeeded)
                    {
                        return RedirectToAction("Manage", new { Message = ManageMessageId.ChangePasswordSuccess });
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        AddErrors(result);
                    }
                }
            }
            else
            {
                ModelState state = ModelState["OldPassword"];
                if (state != null)
                {
                    state.Errors.Clear();
                }

                if (ModelState.IsValid)
                {
                    IdentityResult result = await UserManager.AddPasswordAsync(User.Identity.GetUserId(), model.NewPassword);
                    if (result.Succeeded)
                    {
                        return RedirectToAction("Manage", new { Message = ManageMessageId.SetPasswordSuccess });
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        AddErrors(result);
                    }
                }
            }

            return View(model);
        }
```

This currently updates the password. But what if I want to change model's username? How can I modify this code? I know some programming but I have no idea to modify this code? I welcome any help. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That action looks specific to changing a password. I would create a different action and view to modify the other fields you want to change like username, email, etc. The table Users is available through the identity context so you could follow the typical pattern of setting up the Get, View and Post:

First make a viewmodel of what you want to allow editing on:

```
public class UserUpdateViewModel
{
    [Required]
    [MaxLength(50)]
    public string UserName { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [MaxLength(50)]
    public string FirstName { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [MaxLength(50)]
    public string LastName { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [EmailAddress]
    [MaxLength(255)]
    public string Email { get; set; }
}
```

Then create the Get action:

```
    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult Edit(string id, ManageMessageId? message = null)
    {
        var user = _db.Users.First(u => u.UserName == id);
        // move entity fields to viewmodel from constructor, automapper, etc.        
        var model = new UserUpdateViewModel 
        {
            UserName = user.UserName,
            FirstName = user.FirstName,
            LastName = user.LastName,
            Email = user.Email
        };  
        ViewBag.MessageId = message;
        return View(model);
    }
```

Then make a view followed by the Post:

```
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public async Task<ActionResult> Edit(UserUpdateViewModel userUpdateViewModel)
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid) return View(userUpdateViewModel);

        var user = _db.Users.First(u => u.UserName == userUpdateViewModel.UserName);
        // Mapper.Map(userUpdateViewModel, user);  // move viewmodel to entity model
        // instead of automapper, you can do this:
        user.UserName = userUpdateViewModel.UserName;
        user.FirstName = userUpdateViewModel.FirstName;
        user.LastName = userUpdateViewModel.LastName;
        user.Email = userUpdateViewModel.Email;

        await _db.SaveChangesAsync();

        return this.RedirectToAction(a => a.Index()).WithSuccess("User updated.");
    }
```

Comment: `var model = new UserUpdateViewModel(user);  // move entity fields to viewmodel from constructor, automapper, etc` I couldn't understand this part, this line gives error to create a constructor.

Comment: Yes, you can create a constructor to copy the fields from the entity model, or you can just do it manually or use automapper. I will edit to show the manual method since there are only a few fields.

Comment: I have an error for your ViewModel, it says it has no key defined.. What should I do for that? Thank you.

Comment: Where are you getting the error? You shouldn't need a key since we are fetching an entity (user) and then replacing the changed fields based on the view model. I am using automapper in the example above to do that, but you could just assign the properties manually as we did for the get. I'll change the POST similarly.

Comment: you need a [Key] attribute from system.componentmodel.DataAnnotations  on your primary key property of your user class

Comment: No, he doesn't. User is inherited from IdentityUser which marks the key. The issue is trying to save a viewmodel.